# Scroll bar scrolls but UIScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have components in a UIScrollView. My scroll view works when it was in iOS 10 and Xcode 8 but after the update, my scroll view does not scroll. However, the scroll bar does scroll and can keep scrolling until it gets smaller and smaller. It is just the elements in the scroll view itself that doesn't scroll.

I have tried doing content size bigger than the frame size but it does not fix it. Here is my current views hierarchy.

[image]

If anyone can help me debug this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure it worked before? it seems to me, that you use autolayout, but don't have contentView inside your scrollView

Comment: @VladHatko Yeah it worked before. Is contentView just a UIView inside the ScrollView?

Comment: yes, you've done it in your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a content view to the scroll view, and then the scroll view should be the subview of main view. The hierarchy should look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered pretty much the same problem (scroll indicator moves and gets smaller but content doesn't move). In my case it was resolved by changing the AutoLayout constraint for the top of my content view within the UIScrollView. I had pinned it to the Frame Layout Guide rather than the top of the superview.